# MVC 3 Soulution organisation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to build an application using MVC 3, I know from the start that the application will be fairly complex with lots of different sections containing different areas of functionality.

What I am attempting to do is separate out this functionality into class libraries which include the views, I have set the build folder of the class library to an areas folder within the MVC application and copied a Razor view engine from Wayne Haffenden's [blog post](http://www.waynehaffenden.com/Blog/ASPNET-MVC-3-Razor-CSharp-View-Engine) This has not worked at all.

I have also tried to use MEF which I can get to work using MVC2 but not MVC3. Does anyone have any suggestion of how I might accomplish this or even better a few examples where this has all ready been done.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a physical need to separate the assemblies?  If not, use folders.  Don't create new assemblies just for organizational purposes.  As you can see they come with very high complexity cost and it sounds like there is no reason for it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [MvcContrib's portable areas](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/hex/archive/2009/11/01/asp-net-mvc-portable-areas-via-mvccontrib.aspx) that offer support for this. But in general I would agree with jfar that seperating an MVC project into different assemblies (that include views) is not easy right now.

Answer (score 0):

I have a fairly large MVC 3 application (3 sites) in which I use Areas extensively. My controllers get all their data from repositories (referenced from another project) and I have another project called MyProject.Web.Shared which contains common code such as Attributes, Filters, Extensions, HtmlHelpers etc.

Although I have a little bit of code duplication in my views I feel it strikes a good balance between the DRY principle and extensibility, as I treat all my sites (and views) as individual entities as the needs within each site may change over time. I find that using Areas to separate separate functionality works really well.